# Can I choose to manually update weights in my neural network to allow an essentially infinite batch size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am feeding large images into my CNN, and for some reason, converting the images to grayscale or making my network much smaller has no impact whatsoever on my maximum batch size. If I do anything more than 4, I run out of memory on my 16GB cpu. I am loading in each batch at a time, but I still run into memory issues. I was wondering if instead, using Tensorflow (or Keras with TF backend preferably), I could load in one image at a time, updating the gradient approximation and with each image, and only updating the weights after each batch is done.

In theory, this should allow me to make the batch size as large as I want, as long as I have enough memory for feeding one picture in at a time. Am I wrong in this thinking? Are there any built-in functions to Keras and Tensorflow that I am missing that would help with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a batch generator. With Keras see [`model.fit_generator`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator).

Define your generator similarly to (taken from the docs):

```
def generate_arrays_from_file(path):
    while True:
        with open(path) as f:
            for line in f:
                # create numpy arrays of input data
                # and labels, from each line in the file
                x1, x2, y = process_line(line)
                yield ({'input_1': x1, 'input_2': x2}, {'output': y})
```

And then fit the generator into your model.

```
model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_from_file('/my_file.txt'),
                    steps_per_epoch=10000, epochs=10)
```

To avoid memory issues, pass the argument `max_queue_size=1` to `fit_generator`, so only a single batch is loaded in the queue.

Comment: Thank you, I looked at generators from the Keras documentation, but couldn't find this code snippet for some reason which clears it up way better.